# Can a character multiclassed into Bard multiclass into a third or fourth class by taking the Multiclass Mastery feat?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, multi-classing

> **Multiclass Mastery**
>    **Prerequisites:** 21st level, Bard
>    **Benefit:** Gain two multiclass feats for which you meet the prerequisites.

If a character (a wizard, for instance) multiclasses as a bard with Bardic Ritualist (for example), and later takes the above feat at level 21 or above, which multiclass feats is the character able to choose from?

Can this character pick Initiate of the Old Faith (multiclass into Druid) and Acolyte of Divine Secrets (multiclass into Invoker)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, you can't gain additional classes.

While you *can* take the feat Multiclass Mastery, it doesn't give you the ability to multiclass into more than one class if you don't already have that ability (for example, from being a Bard as your main class and thus having Multiclass Versatility). Multiclass Mastery does not say it allows you to ignore the prerequisites for the feats you take, which includes not having a class-specific multiclass feat for a different class, so you don't qualify for any that aren't for the Bard class.

#### However, you *can* take the feat and get some benefit from it.

Although you can't gain additional classes, there are still a few options left to you. After you've taken a class-specific multiclass feat, you no longer qualify for most multiclass feats, but you can still take *other* Bard multiclass feats. So whichever feats of Bardic Ritualist, Bardic Dilettante, and Master of Stories that you haven't already taken are options, as long as you meet their prerequisites.

Further, the power-swap feats Acolyte Power, Adept Power, and Novice Power count as multiclass feats (and are obviously available when you have a class-specific multiclass feat), so they are also options.

Comment: But the wording of the feat [MM] does seem quite clear. Acolyte of Divine Secrets is a multiclass feat (MC into Invoker), and the listed prerequisite is Wis 13, so MM should allow me to take it. The usual restriction (which Multiclass Versatility [MV] normally bypasses) is "once you take a multiclass feat, you can’t take a class-specific feat for a different class", but does this still restrict what MM allows me to choose?

Comment: @Zso As stated, Multiclass Mastery does not change the normal restrictions on taking multiclass feats. It's a "two for the price of one" feat, that's the only effect it has. The only reason Bards can take multiclass feats from more than one class is because of their Multiclass Versatility class feature, which no feat grants.

Comment: @Zso You can also see it in action if you try it in the character builder, as shown here: http://imgur.com/49LIb3L

Comment: Okay, I'll accept the character builder's rules as conclusive, but from the wording of the feat, I'm still not seeing the order in which rules come into effect to make this not an option. How is this not a case of 'specific beats general'? The feat comes into effect after the general rule of 'one class-specific MC feat only', and the wording of the feat only lists the prerequisite of the class-specific MC feat as being relevant to whether you can take it. "You can take a MC feat if you meet the listed prerequisite" is essentially how it's written (ignoring the second feat also granted for now)

Comment: @Zso I'm not seeing what the problem is here. Multiclass Mastery doesn't say anything about which multiclass feats you can take, doesn't say anything about changing prerequisites, it just says "take two multiclass feats." The general rule is that you must qualify for a feat to be able to take it. There's no specific rule given to say otherwise. "Not having a multiclass feat for a different class" is a global prerequisite for multiclass feats that they just don't print on each one, just like the restriction that you can't take multiclass feats for your base class.

Comment: "doesn't say anything about changing prerequisites" But I'm not suggesting it changed the prerequisite. The only prerequisite for Acolyte of Divine Secrets is Wis 13, and it's a MC feat. Multiclass Mastery says I can gain two MC feats for which I meet the prerequisites. I have Wis 13. Therefore I can take Multiclass Mastery and pick Acolyte of Divine Secrets because I meet the only prerequisite. You're saying the general rule of 'One class-specific MC feat per character' still applies and says I can't do this, but this isn't mentioned in the feat, and in fact is overruled by it, by the wording

Comment: @Zso D&D 4e is a game of exceptions. If something doesn't say it changes a rule, it doesn't change a rule. Not repeating the general rule is not the same as being a contradictory specific rule. Multiclass Mastery does not explicitly say that you can take the multiclass feat from any class, therefore, you can't.

Comment: That's what I was getting at earlier, asking whether I was missing something or if the feat was just worded poorly. Because as-written, MM should allow me to ignore the 'one class-specific MM feat per character' rule, following the 'specific trumps general' rule stipulated at the start of the book. "Multiclass Mastery does not explicitly say that you can take the multiclass feat from any class" It just says 'two multiclass feats', making no mentioned of class-specific ones being limited, therefore meaning any MC feat, including class-specific ones.